# I'm looking for an Addon that “assembles” sections of buildings and/or objects in a timelapse like effect

Tags: animation, add-on

Kind of like a transformers effect, but more scaling from nothing and sliding in from nowhere kind of thing. Almost like a timelapse of the building being made. Swear I’ve seen something like this, but can’t find it.

Answer (score 1):

There are no add-ons that do all the work for you. ...yet at least, until AI takes all our jobs away. Until then, if you want some complex very specific animation you have an idea for, you have to make it yourself. If you want to animate a building assembling out of nothing, it still has to have all the parts that it would be made of. You need to create those at least.

If you choose to animate it manually(which is probably pretty much the only choice here), it may not be that difficult once you have a model made of parts. The model made of enough parts for everything to look somewhat realistic/cool would probably be the hardest part here. You could just start with the complete model and animate those parts sliding and scaling away and then just reverse it to look like it happens other way around. Geometry nodes could be used to help with this, but that will not be anything even remotely close to simple or "automatic" single button click like I suspect you would expect from your described mythical add-on.

Oh, and developing the look would also be the hard part - camera angles, lighting, materials, the way parts move and scale and appear and the sequence in which they do so. Animating itself might look like tedious job, and don't get me wrong - it probably would be, but I don't think it would be that hard, because you would only be inserting keyframes and moving and scaling objects a lot of times - so that's pretty easy and actually, even if not that pleasant of a job to do, still quite quick as well.